# How to handle EntityNotFoundException in Abp vNext?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, abp

I was browsing abp's blogging module. There is a code like below in post repo.
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/modules/blogging/src/Volo.Blogging.EntityFrameworkCore/Volo/Blogging/Posts/EfCorePostRepository.cs

```
public async Task<Post> GetPostByUrl(Guid blogId, string url)
{
    var post = await DbSet.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.BlogId == blogId && p.Url == url);

    if (post == null)
    {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException(typeof(Post), nameof(post));
    }

    return post;
}
```

I'm testing module and im getting error like blow if there is no entity.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   EntityNotFoundException: There is no such an entity. Entity type:
>   Volo.Blogging.Posts.Post, id: post
>   Volo.Blogging.Posts.EfCorePostRepository.GetPostByUrl(Guid blogId,
>   string url) in EfCorePostRepository.cs, line 35

It is normal to get this exception if there is no entity, but how to show 404 page or message like there is no record to user? I tried to throw UserFriendlyException but still getting and error page.

Comment: `UserFriendlyException` must show an alert dialog on the web browser.

Comment: I tested UserFriendlyException it's not working as expected. it still show an error page which is contains callstack. Do i have to do something in somewhere of the project to show userfriendly error page.

in abp's blog page if url not found system displays a 404 page as expected.

https://blog.abp.io/abp/ABP-Framework-v2_3_0-Has-Been-Released-blabla

Comment: try in release mode. because debug mode shows standard aspnet error page